# How to get version history using One Drive API

Tags: live-sdk, onedrive

I am using LiveSDK 5.6 to get file and folder info stored in One Drive. I am able to get these info, but Now, I am trying to find file version history. I am not able to find a way to get version history of a file stored in One Drive.

Can anyone suggest me a way to get version history of a file (using Live SDK or REST API ?

Rest API documentation API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659752.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The LiveSDK, unfortunately, won't return version history but will return created_time, updated_time, etc.  The new OneDrive API has a new feature for checking changes made to an item and its children (http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As Toan-Nguyen says, we can't get version number from One Drive APIs now (July 8 2016).
https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm

I want to get file version information from API, so I requested from [Request page](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/15117267-enable-one-drive-api-to-get-file-version-informati). If you want to get version, please vote.